# RESTful WCF service returns "endpoint not found" error on POST operations

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I've built a WCF service that's exposed both through SOAP and RESTfully.  All SOAP actions work as advertised.  GETS/PUTS do as well, but when I try to do a POST to an action in my service, I get the following error returned:

"Endpoint not found"

IPersonEditServiceContract snippet:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", 
   UriTemplate="/persons", 
   RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
   ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
SavePersonResponse SavePerson(SavePersonRequest request);


[OperationContract]
WebGet(UriTemplate = "/persons/{personId}",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
Person GetClaimantById(string personId);
```

Service is configured this way:

```
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
     <webHttp />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        name="DefaultEndpoint"
        bindingNamespace="http://mycompany.com/ServiceContracts"
        contract="IPersonEditServiceContract" />
     <endpoint 
         address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding"
         name="RESTEndpoint" 
         bindingNamespace="http://mycompany.com/ServiceContracts"
         contract="IPersonEditServiceContract" 
         behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Since I can do other RESTful operations against the same endpoint, I'm not entirely sure why it gives me that semi-helpful error.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think WCF is giving the error because it really can't find the endpoint. Are you hitting it using POST to the right URL under /rest? Try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to create POST call.

Comment: it magically went away; have no idea what the problem was.  but, since you're the only one that answered, thanks!  BTW, I use fiddler for simple tests, really like soapUI for building some mocks and test projects from a similar angle.

Comment: Please don't mark the answer unless the question has actually been answered.  Its confusing for users who show up later with the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My HttpGet works, however I created a similar method that I want to use POST with, and I get the endpoint not found error. Did you figure out what the true issue was?

Comment: I am having the same issue, but by saying 'it went away by itself' that isn't helpful. Did you find the issue? With mine the service still works sometimes with a post, but it doesn't always seem to work. Can never browse to it though it just says endpoint not found.

Comment: can we remove this post or unmark the answer somehow, in case a useful response comes around?

Comment: @Chris I can't delete this answer since it's been accepted. Maybe joshua.ewer can post an answer himself and accept it.

Comment: `it magically went away` because requests generated from browsers are `GET` not `POST`, when simulated actual `POST` using fiddler, webmethod is found & thus no error(HTTP 404, 405).